# Java 7 org.threeten port solution for Java 8 Date.from

Tags: java

I have not worked with Java 8 and consequently the new Date API for compatibility. I have a need in a current project to use JJWT for security in a REST Service, and have found the most simple code example project for its use (https://github.com/agoncal/agoncal-sample-jaxrs/tree/master/04-JWT). Unfortunately it seems to use Java 8 and I need to use Java 7 so consequently had to use the org.threeten back port of the Date API. The below code is the last piece I need to convert but am stumped as to how to make it work with the org.threeten port.

```
import org.threeten.bp.LocalDateTime;
import org.threeten.bp.ZoneId;

toDate(LocalDateTime.now().plusMinutes(15L));

private Date toDate(LocalDateTime localDateTime) {
    org.threeten.bp.OffsetDateTime.now();
    localDateTime.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant();
    return Date.from(localDateTime.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
}
```

Answer (score 5):

## `DateTimeUtils`

If your Question is how to convert between the terrible legacy class `java.util.Date` and the modern `Instant` class when using *ThreeTen-Backport*, the Answer is the [`DateTimeUtils`](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/apidocs/org/threeten/bp/DateTimeUtils.html) class.

```
java.util.Date d = DateTimeUtils.toDate( instant ) ;
```

And the other direction.

```
Instant instant = DateTimeUtils.toInstant( myJavaUtilDate ) ;
```

## `LocalDateTime`

By the way, `LocalDateTime` is the wrong class to be using here. That class should never be used when you are tracking moments. Lacking any concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC, that class cannot represent a moment.

Tracking a moment requires you to place the date and time-of-day in the context of a time zone (or offset). So for a moment you must use one of these:

- `Instant`
- `OffsetDateTime`
- `ZonedDateTime`

This has been covered many many times already on Stack Overflow. Search to learn more.

```
DateTimeUtils
.toDate(
    ZonedDateTime
    .now(
        ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" )
    )
    .plusMinutes( 15 )
    .toInstant()
) // Returns a `java.util.Date` object.
```